# Executing Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table: View_Attachments_201401  (the last part being in YYYYMM format). Now, I am trying to reference this table in a much more bigger query running for each month of the year.

What I am trying to achieve in short is this and unfortunately it gives an error. Could you please help me? I am using Sybase 16.

```
Create variable @sqlstring varchar(255);
Create variable @yyyymm    varchar(6);
Set @yyyymm = '201404';
Set @sqlstring = 'Select distinct hdtv from tbl.View_attachments_@yyyymm';
Execute @sqlstring
```

Comment: If you are trying to reference `View_Attachments_201401`, why is your date set to `'201404'`.

Comment: Syntax error near '@sqlstring'

Comment: @GordonLinoff These tables go back to 201201.

Comment: @user1950075 Does this query `Select distinct hdtv from tbl.View_attachments_201404` work?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Declare @sqlstring varchar(255);
Declare @yyyymm    varchar(6);
Set @yyyymm = '201404';
Set @sqlstring = 'Select distinct hdtv from tbl.View_attachments_' + @yyyymm;
execute ( @sqlstring )
```

Comment: says Procedure '@sqlstring' not found

Comment: Thanks for trying, still gives Syntax error near 'end' on line 5 @JChao

Comment: Try it as it is above now `execute ( @sqlstring )`

Comment: @user1950075 I'm not sure. Maybe it doesn't like the spaces. Whatever it is you are very close.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare 
@sqlstring varchar(255),
@yyyymm    varchar(6)

select @yyyymm = '201404'
select @sqlstring = 'Select distinct hdtv from tbl.View_attachments_' + @yyyymm

execute ( @sqlstring )
```